# Adding integers in list

Tags: prolog

For some reason, this is not working. I am getting:
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

```
1 add_list([]).
2 add_list([H|T]):-
3                 Sum2 is Sum1 + H,
4                 add_list(T).
```

I am trying to add the contents of a list (containing only numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But if you are trying to calc total sum it will be this way (changed name to list_sum as add_list doesn't make any sense):

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([H|T], Sum):-
    list_sum(T, SubSum),
    Sum is SubSum + H.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to get too. But I think I am a bit confused about recursion in prolog. list_sum([], 0). is this the base case? And is 0 achieved because there is no elements left in the list?

Comment: Fist line is "fact". The second line is "rule". You must reach fact from rule. I know it's little bit strange, but you should read about prolog little bit more (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a "functionnal mind" with foldl :

```
foldl(_P, [], V, V).

foldl(P, [H|T], V1, VF) :-
    call(P, H, V1, V2),
    foldl(P, T, V2, VF).


sum_list(L, S) :-
    foldl(add, L, 0, S).


add(X, Y, Z) :-
    Z is X+Y.
```

Comment: s(X) for going higher-order!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also use an accumulator (the advantage is, that it is tail-recursive and therefore can be optimized)

```
list_sum(L,R) :- list_sum(L,0,R).   
list_sum([],A,A). 
list_sum([H|T],A,R) :- A1 is A + H, list_sum(T,A1,R).
```